# jQuery, Rails 4: removing Class from Element inside Loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I tried to seamlessly update my Rails Model Object but I'm struggling with applying changes to the DOM with JavaScript.
Here is what I've tried:
*View*

```
- current_user.ordered_notifications.limit(3).each do |notification|
    = link_to(update_notification_read_user_path(id: notification.id), remote: true) do
        %i.fa.fa-eye.active.inline
    = link_to(update_notifications_user_path(id: notification.id)) do
        %h5.active.inline
            = notification.title
        %i.fa.fa-angle-right.active.inline
```

*User Controller*

```
def update_notification_read
  notification = current_user.ordered_notifications.find(params[:id])
  notification.read = true
  notification.save!

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to search_path }
    format.js # render comments/update_notification_read.js
  end
end
```

*JS File*

```
$('.active').removeClass('active');
```

The code above works! I am just struggling with only applying the changes to `this` particular Element, because I have a loop which contains multiple elements.

Thanks in advance for any help! Please tell me if you need additional information.

Comment: Does 'this' have a particular condition?

Comment: @Stephen C What do you exactly mean? An id or something similar?

Comment: Well, the question is vague on what you're trying to achieve with 'this'. What are you trying to target? Are you trying to add/remove the class active on a particular condition? such as 'if notification.read?'

Comment: it's better if you create multiple links into the loop, you identify each link|element with an unique id and then your java script use those ids $('#active_1').removeClass('active'); $('.active_2').removeClass('active');

Comment: @Stephen C I just want to target `this`. The rest is rails doing automatically.

Comment: @johnnynemonic The problem is, that the haml I provided is multiplied several times on the page. I want to edit all `active` elements which belong together. With your suggestion, I would target one element inside of each loop-item. I edited the View code in the question to make that easier to understand